# Is it possible to build a Linux docker image on VSTS 2017 Hosted agent?

Tags: linux, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, docker-build

I've got a Dockerfile that pulls from a base image of `microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime`. When I do a build locally (on windows running Linux containers) I get a Linux docker image.

however, if we run the same build process on VSTS using a 2017 Hosted agent then we get a windows docker image.

Is it possible to build a Linux docker image on VSTS 2017 Hosted agent without having to use a Linux build agent?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a Linux build agent?  There are Hosted Linux build agents.

Comment: They're in 'preview'

Comment: Looks like they will be moving out of preview in the next couple of weeks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#build-and-release-with-microsoft-hosted-linux-and-macos-agents

Comment: At this time, the ubuntu agent is out of preview and is able to build linux docker images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to build a Linux docker image with VSTS Hosted VS2017 agent. Hosted VS2017 agent can only build for Windows docker images.

The workarounds to build Linux docker image as below:

- Build with Hosted Linux Preview agent
- Build with [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) with your own windows machine